# Colour sensor(TCS230) interfacing not works with ATMEGA16?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, atmega, arduino-ide

Sir i dont know why my C-code for Colour sensor not working. i am using ATMEGA16 microcontroller and the sensor i am using is TCS230 sensor which is connected to TO pin PB0(PORTB0) of microcontroller. please help me i am attaching my c-code here--Remember that i am using 20% scaling and already connect the S0 an S1 pin with 1(VCC) and 0(Gnd).

```
  #define S2 PA0
  #define S3 PA1 
  #define F_CPU 11.0592
  #include <util/delay.h>
  #include<avr/io.h>
  #include<avr/interrupt.h>
  //Variable declarations
  unsigned char state;
  unsigned int counter_r,counter_g,counter_b,counter_no;
  unsigned char i=0; //to store value of counter
  unsigned char flag=0;
void chkcolour();

 int main()
  { 
    DDRB=0x00; //PB0 and T0(counter pin ) Input
    DDRA=0xFF; //PA2(R),PA3(G) & PA4(B) for RGB LED ,PA0(S2) & PA1(S3) for RGB selection ,Output Pins
    TCNT0=0x00;
    TCCR0=0x07;
    state=0; //start from 0 then 1,2,then again same

     sei();

    while(1)
     { flag=0;
switch(state)
{
   case 0:

       PORTA=0b00000000; //For Red
        _delay_ms(1000);
        counter_r=TCNT0;
        TCNT0=0x00;
        state=1;

   case 1:       

       PORTA=0b00000010; //For blue
        _delay_ms(1000);
       counter_b=TCNT0;
       TCNT0=0x00;
       state=2;

   case 2:  
         PORTA=0b00000011; //For Green
         _delay_ms(1000);
         counter_g=TCNT0;
         TCNT0=0x00;
         state=3;

   case 3:
       PORTA=0b00000001; //No Filter
       _delay_ms(1000);
       counter_no=TCNT0;
       TCNT0=0x00;
       state=0;
       break;

 } 


chkcolour();

}

return 0;
}



void chkcolour()
{


        if((counter_r > counter_b) && (counter_r > counter_g) )
            {
          PORTA=0b00000100; //Glow RED LED,Off Green LED,Off Blue LED 
          flag=1;


           }    

        else if((counter_g > counter_r) && (counter_g > counter_b))
         {
         PORTA=0b00001000; //Glow GEREEN LED,Off RED LED,Off Blue LED 
         flag=1;


          } 

         else if((counter_b > counter_r) && (counter_b > counter_g)  )
         {
         PORTA=0b00010000; //Glow BLUE LED,Off RED LED,Off GREEN LED 
         flag=1;


          } 


    else 
          {
         PORTA=0b00000000; //0ff GEREEN LED,Off RED LED,Off Blue LED 
         flag=1;


          }


}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 0):

Many issues.

1) don't forget to add **break** into *switch* after each *case* block

2) assignments to PORTA overwrite previous value in this port. I.e. in this construction:

```
     PORTA=(0<<PORTA2); //Off RED LED 
     PORTA=(1<<PORTA3); //Glow Green LED 
     PORTA=(0<<PORTA4); //off Blue LED
```

you will have a zero (last line) on all the outputs of the PORTA.

3) Even, if something will out to PORTA in chkcolour(), it will be overwritten in next couple of microseconds, because in next iteration it will be assigned:

```
   PORTA=(0<<S3) | (0<<S2) ; //For Red
```

*To set or clear bits* use construction like this:

```
PORTA |= (1 << bitnum); // to set a bit
PORTA &= ~(1 << bitnum); // to clear (note bitwise negation ~ symbol)
```

Comment: sir i am not using break at every case because i want to send my 'control' to the next state..and i have made some changes in my code based on your suggestion but it still not works...please help

Comment: Then, why you need to use "switch" at all? Look again: whatever will be output to PORTA in chkcolour(), it immediately will be overwritten by PORTA=0b00000000; in your switch. Use PORTA= (PORTA & 0b11111100) | zz; instead.  where zz - 0b00 0b01 0b10 0b11 (last two bits for each "case")

Comment: Sir please check this question and give your sugesstion ------- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730103/counting-without-counter-in-microcontroller-is-possible